# Creating a timeout using time and difftime

Tags: c

```
gcc (GCC) 4.6.0 20110419 (Red Hat 4.6.0-5)
```

I am trying to get the time of start and end time. And get the difference between them.

The function I have is for creating a API for our existing hardware.

The API wait_events take one argument that is time in milli-seconds. So what I am trying to get the start before the while loop. And using time to get the number of seconds. Then after 1 iteration of the loop get the time difference and then compare that difference with the time out.

Many thanks for any suggestions,

```
/* Wait for an event up to a specified time out.
 * If an event occurs before the time out return 0
 * If an event timeouts out before an event return -1 */
int wait_events(int timeout_ms)
{
    time_t start = 0;
    time_t end = 0;
    double time_diff = 0;
    /* convert to seconds */
    int timeout = timeout_ms / 100;

    /* Get the initial time */
    start = time(NULL);
    while(TRUE) {
        if(open_device_flag == TRUE) {
            device_evt.event_id = EVENT_DEV_OPEN;
            return TRUE;
        }
        /* Get the end time after each iteration */
        end = time(NULL);
        /* Get the difference between times */
        time_diff = difftime(start, end);
        if(time_diff > timeout) {
            /* timed out before getting an event */
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
}
```

The function that will call will be like this.

```
int main(void)
{
#define TIMEOUT 500 /* 1/2 sec */
    while(TRUE) {
        if(wait_events(TIMEOUT) != 0) {
            /* Process incoming event */
            printf("Event fired\n");
        }
        else {
            printf("Event timed out\n");
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

=============== EDIT with updated results ==================

```
1) With no sleep -> 99.7% - 100% CPU
2) Setting usleep(10) -> 25% CPU
3) Setting usleep(100) -> 13% CPU
3) Setting usleep(1000) -> 2.6% CPU
4) Setting usleep(10000) -> 0.3 - 0.7% CPU
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're overcomplicating it - simplified:

```
time_t start = time();
for (;;) {
    // try something
    if (time() > start + 5) {
        printf("5s timeout!\n");
        break;
    }
}
```

`time_t` should in general just be an `int` or `long int` depending on your platform counting the number of seconds since January 1st 1970.

Side note:

```
int timeout = timeout_ms / 1000;
```

One second consists of 1000 milliseconds.

Edit - another note:
You'll most likely have to ensure that the other thread(s) and/or event handling can happen, so include some kind of thread inactivity (using `sleep()`, `nanosleep()` or whatever).

Comment: Hello Mario. That worked. Thanks. Yes, this will be a multi-threaded application. So in the while loop where I am checking the time. I should put a sleep in there to pause the current thread, so that other threads can happen. However, if this was multi-thread. Those threads would happen anyway, because they would be in another thread? Is that what you mean? Thanks.

Comment: They should (really depending on your OS's scheduler) but your application will sit at 100% even though it's idling and that might as well slow down the other threads you're waiting for. If you don't want to risk any slow downs, just wait for 0 milliseconds. This sounds stupid but it will provide the OS with a convenient point where it's able to task switch and process events even though you're not waiting at all (on paper).

Comment: Hello Mario, I have updated my question with some updated results. Which one would you say was the optimum you could sleep for? Thanks.

Comment: That really depends on the responsiveness you'd like to observe/accept. Sure, a 10 seconds timeout will cause very low CPU load however it will as well force a 10 seconds wait time which might cause the program and/or hardware to appear inactive, hung, unresponsive or just ... slow. Just pick a sane value that's acceptable for your design, usage, customers, etc.

Comment: The C function time() takes one argument.  Calling it without any arguments results in undefined behaviour - though almost all of the time it will be equivalent to time(NULL).
This is very bad as the time function may overwrite memory anywhere.  If you are lucky you will get a memory violation. However, the compiler should warn of this problem if there is a prototype for time() available.

Answer (score 2):

Without calling a Sleep() function this a really bad design : your loop will use 100% of the CPU. Even if you are using threads, your other threads won't have much time to run as this thread will use many CPU cycles.
You should design something like that:

```
while(true) {
  Sleep(100); // lets say you want a precision of 100 ms
  // Do the compare time stuff here
}
```

If you need precision of the timing and are using different threads/processes, use Mutexes ([semaphores](http://tldp.org/LDP/lpg/node46.html#SECTION00743000000000000000) with a increment/decrement of 1) or Critical Sections to make sure the time compare of your function is not interrupted by another process/thread of your own.
I believe your Red Hat is a [System V](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UNIX_System_V) so you can sync using [IPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication)

Comment: Hello Dranfi, I did set the sleep to 100. I have also displayed this as my updated results in my question. Thanks.

Comment: I am really surprised with your results : 
Setting usleep(100) -> 13% CPU.
That's still  a lot of CPU cycles for a loop iterating only 10 times/s.
May I ask on which CPU (and OS) you execute this code?